# She has taught English for five years

Tags: present-tense

Is the verb "teach" used like the verbs "live", "work" and "study" which can be used in both the present perfect and the progressive without any change of meaning?

To say that the person is still teaching English can I use the present perfect in my sentence instead of the progressive?
"She has taught English for five years" instead of "she has been teaching."

Comment: Yes, you can - that is a natural thing to say.

Comment: And the meaning is the same as with the present perfect continuous, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is the same.